# How to connect to odcb database with excel vbs

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, adodb

thx to google I figured out a lot of weird tricks you can do to connect to simple SQL server or SAP database and such. However, no matter how hard I try I can not create odbc object.

I can pull odbc database to excel, but this is not what I want to do.
I want to use INSERT and DELETE SQL queries.

The simplest line of codes I found were these:

```
Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection

    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & "SERVER=******.****.**;" & "DATABASE=testServer;" & "USER=Mikk;" & "PASSWORD=**;" & "Option=3"
End Sub
```

I have ticked the box for ActiveX data object 2.8 Library

I get run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)
Automation error
Unspecified error

Comment: Not sure how stack overflow works, do I have to bump?
And what does score -1 mean? I need to explain something more?
Or excel can not establish odbc databse connection objects?

Answer (score 0):

Money solves problems :)

I didn't use the correct database name and did not use DSN.
Also using a specific driver was not a good idea.
Even the server aadress was not needed.

Here is the solution:

```
Sub test_connection()
  Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim strUsername As String
  Dim strPassword As String
  Dim strDatabase As String

  strUsername = "Mikk"
  strPassword = "****"
  strDatabase = "test"

  oConn.Open "DSN=testServer;" & _
    "Database=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
    "Uid=" & strUsername & ";" & _
    "Pwd=" & strPassword

  oConn.Close
  Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```